# How can I change the text inside CardBody(html.H6) with a callback function (dash python)?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Inside the app.layout I have an input, and when I type some info in it, I want to change the info of the CardBody(html.H6).
Trying this way I’ve been having errors like this:

TypeError: The `dash_bootstrap_components.Card` component (version 0.12.0) with the ID "CardBody(children={}, id='card_title1')" detected a Component for a prop other than `children`
Did you forget to wrap multiple `children` in an array?
Prop id has value CardBody(children={}, id='card_title1')

```
# This is inside app.layout:

html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown', 
            options=[{'label':i, 'value':i} for i in df['c'].unique()],
        ),
        html.Div(id='output') 
    ], className='search-bar'),


html.Div(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(children=[
                    dbc.Card(dbc.CardHeader("Diretor"),
                    dbc.CardBody([
                        html.H6({}, id='card_title1', className="card-title1"),
                        ]), inverse=True)]),
            ],
            className="mb-4 cardsrow",
        ),
    ]
),


### Callback function:

@app.callback(
    Output('card-title1', 'children'),
    Input('dropdown', 'value')
)
def update_output_div(stock_slctd):
    if stock_slctd in df.CNPJ_FUNDO.unique():
        dff = df[df['FUNDO_CODE']==stock_slctd]
    else:
        dff = df[df['FUND_NAME']==stock_slctd]

        name = dff.DIR.iloc[0]
    return name
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
dbc.Card(
    dbc.CardHeader("Diretor"),
    dbc.CardBody(
        [
            html.H6(
                {},
                id="card_title1",
                className="card-title1",
            ),
        ]
    ),
    inverse=True,
)
```

You should wrap multiple children in an array as the error is telling you:

```
dbc.Card(
    children=[
        dbc.CardHeader("Diretor"),
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.H6(
                    {},
                    id="card_title1",
                    className="card-title1",
                ),
            ]
        ),
    ],
    inverse=True,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still not working! =/

Comment: @HenriqueNader When you say it doesn't work do you mean you still get that `Did you forget to wrap multiple children?` error or something different? If it's the former check if there are other instances where you don't wrap multiple children in an array. Either way here's a minimal working example [patebin](https://pastebin.com/TQJg7zBm).

Comment: Sorry about that, It's not showing that error anymore, but the @app.callback is not working. Can you please check if there is any mistake in this: https://pastebin.com/pcxRMuV5